# Cambiar un campo de la clase padre en los modelos de Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo una clase padre donde tengo un atributo que deseo modificar según la clase hijo:

```
class Service(models.Model):
   # otros atributos
   SERVICE_TYPE = {
       'None': 'Unknown service type',
       'visa': 'Visa',
   }
   service_type = None

   def get_service_type(self):
       if self.service_type:
           return self.service_type
       else:
           return self.SERVICE_TYPE['None']
```

Y tengo varias clases que heredan de esta, una de ellas es la siguiente:

```
class Visa(Service):
    # atributos de esta clase
```

El problema es que cuando creo un objeto de tipo `Visa` el atributo `service_type` de la clase padre `Service` nunca se modifica (siempre es None). He tratado de modificar el método `save` de `Model` y tambien modificarlo directamente en la vista para crear y no funciona.

## modificando el método `save`:

```
class Visa(Service):
    # atributes
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.service_type = 'visa'
    return super(Visa, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

## modificando el atributo en la vista:

```
class ServiceCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.service_type = 'visa'
        return super(ServiceCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo la documentación de Django sobre [Herencia de modelos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) encontré una forma de poder acceder al valor de la clase padre. Así es como quedarían los modelos:

#### models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    # otros atributos
    SERVICE_TYPE = {
        'None': 'Tipo de servicio desconocido',
        'visa': 'Visado',
        'passport': 'Pasaporte',
    }
    service_type = None

    def get_service_type(self):
        if self.service_type:
            return self.SERVICE_TYPE[self.service_type]
        else:
            return self.SERVICE_TYPE['None']

class Visa(Service):
    # atributos de la clase Visa
    service_type = 'visa'

class Passport(Service):
    # atributos de la clase Passport
    service_type = 'passport'
```

Entonces en la plantilla quedaría así:

#### templates/index.html

```
{% if service.visa %}
    {{ service.visa.get_service_type }}
{% elif service.passport %}
    {{ service.passport.get_service_type }}
{% else %}
    {{ service.get_service_type }}
{% endif %}
```

Mostrando **Visado** si el objeto es de la clase `Visa` o muestra **Pasaporte** si es una instancia de la clase `Passport`. Si no pertenece a ninguna de estas clases, entonces muestra **Tipo de servicio desconocido**.